# Replace the char conditionally using awk script

Tags: awk

I have below file1

```
22392003|28|ABC
22392004|28|ABC
22392006|28|XYZ
22392002|28|XYZ
```

this is another file2

```
MR30011596|user||IM1450029|22392099|28|AAA|28
MR30011596|user||IM1450029|22392099|28|BBB|28
MR30011596|user||IM1450029|22392006|28|CCC|28
MR30011596|user||IM1450029|22392099|28|DDD|28
```

I want to search $1 of file1 into file2 at location $5, if match found then replace $3 of file1 into file2 at location $7
so here should be the final output

```
MR30011596|user||IM1450029|22392099|28|AAA|28
MR30011596|user||IM1450029|22392099|28|BBB|28
*MR30011596|user||IM1450029|22392006|28|XYZ|28*
MR30011596|user||IM1450029|22392099|28|DDD|28
```

I tried search char using `awk -F "|" 'FNR==NR { a[$1]; next } $5 in a'` but dont know how to replace $3 into file2 at location $7
Can we achieve this using `awk script`

Comment: `*` is also a part of outpu?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, no its not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"}NR==FNR{a[$1]=$3;next}$5 in a{$7=a[$5]}1' file1 file2
```

the above line gives you the output. (without the `*`)

Comment: I am trying with more fields to be replaced in file2, e.g. match of $1 of file1 found at $5 in file2. Then can we replace multiple chars from file1 to file2. As you answered $7 replaced from $3 in file2. Can we replace more chars like replace $3 of file2 from $2 of file1 as well in one hit. so the output would be  `MR30011596|user||IM1450029|22392099|28|AAA|28` 
`MR30011596|user||IM1450029|22392099|28|BBB|28`
`MR30011596|user|28|IM1450029|22392006|28|XYZ|28`
`MR30011596|user||IM1450029|22392099|28|DDD|28`

Answer (score 0):

You could also accomplish this with two invocations of `join`:

```
# The input needs to be sorted on the join fields
sort             file1 > file1.sorted
sort -t'|' -k5,5 file2 > file2.sorted

(
  join -t'|' -2 5     -o '2.1 2.2 2.3 2.4 2.5 2.6 1.3 2.8' file1.sorted file2.sorted
  join -t'|' -2 5 -v2 -o '2.1 2.2 2.3 2.4 2.5 2.6 2.7 2.8' file1.sorted file2.sorted
)
```

Output:

```
MR30011596|user||IM1450029|22392006|28|XYZ|28
MR30011596|user||IM1450029|22392099|28|AAA|28
MR30011596|user||IM1450029|22392099|28|BBB|28
MR30011596|user||IM1450029|22392099|28|DDD|28
```